# Ubuntu freezes when playing games or multitasking

Tags: partitioning, games, freeze

I installed Ubuntu in this desktop PC for the first time and I don't know what's wrong with it.
The problem is the whole system freezes often, especially when playing games like Steam Project Zomboid, multitasking programs or sometimes just setting some basic things in Settings.
When freezed I always have to shut the system down from the power button.

Here is specific details:
I recently installed Ubuntu on the additional SSD next to the Windows 10 M1-SSD. [I tried switching GeForce drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kB1An.png) but most don't even work.
[This is my system info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgrD5.png). I could show terminal results if asked. I tried reinstalling, updating, upgrading, etc. Ubuntu, but same problems persist.

Question:
[I noticed that an additional Partition 2 (Extended Partition) is allocated in the same memory of the Partition 5 Ubuntu install ext4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDd6O.png). Size is 240 GB for both partitions. SSD is that size. How is this possible and is it good?

Thanks for your time.